# Rails - Nested Objects Deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller, nested-resources

I want to delete the nested object `book`, that is owned by a `user`. In the `user#show` page appears all the `books` related to that `user`. Besides each book there is a link to `delete` it. Here is my code:

`routes.rb`:

```
 resources :users do
   resources :books, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
 end
```

`book_controller.rb`:

```
def destroy
  @user= User.find(params[:user])
  @book = Book.find(params[:book])
  @book.destroy
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

And in the `user#show` page:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", user_book_path(current_user, book), :method => :delete %>
```

I know this is wrong, but how can I do it in order to deleted the wanted book?

Comment: The code you are showing us does not make much sense. In which controller is the `destroy` method? How are book and user related?

Comment: Gonna edit the question.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are deleting you can forget about the fact that it's a nested resource. You know which book you are talking about, so you can just delete it directly.

Routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :books, :only => [:new, :create]
end

resources :books, :only => :destroy
```

Book controller:

```
def destroy
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @book.destroy
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", book_path(book), :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer! I've been searching for this information for 45 minutes.